# Android: Problem in Transparent Bottom Navigation inside the Bottom App Bar

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android, android-bottomappbar, android-bottomnavigationview

I am trying to achieve this kind of Bottom App Bar.

[image: Goal]

I manage to do this.
[image]

Then I put `app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"`
in Bottom navigation but it turns out as shown below. It's not that properly set as transparent.

[image]

**Layout code:**

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="20dp">
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu="@menu/app_bar_menu" />
    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the shadow of the `BottomNavigationView`. Use:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome this helps me a lot, Thanks!

Comment: this didn't helped me :(